# Google Search Console says URLs blocked by robots.txt even after robots.txt is updated

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, robots.txt

Yoast SEO had created a sitemap and robots.txt that did not suit my page. I have since replaced both and waited a few weeks but my robots.txt is still blocking 13 pages. Can anyone help me with what I might be doing wrong?

Here are tags of the pages that are being blocked:

```
https://micronanalytical.com
/sp/
/samples-submissions/
/cr/
/analytical-laboratory-directions/
/analytical-news/
/sem/
/forms-downloads/
/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/2.FDA-License-2018.pdf    
/laboratory-services/
```

Here is my robotstxt

```
robots.txt
User-agent: *
Disallow: /quote/
Disallow: /forms-downloads/
Disallow: /MA/
```

Here is my sitemap: https://micronanalytical.com/sitemap.xml

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What tool is telling you those are all blocked?  It looks like only `/forms-downloads/
` is blocked.   My guess is that either the tool has problems, or it hasn't updated its data with your new robots.txt file.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller google search console is telling me this

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thank you for letting me know it should work. It took awhile to update but finally came thorough. Now showing correctly.